ObjectInputStream Stuck at Initialization when creating one on both Client and Server
ObjectInputStream will initialize just fine when only creating an ObjectInputStream on the Client Side and an ObjectOutputStream on the server side, but when then creating the ObjectInputStream on the Server side, the execution just halts indefinitely. What could cause this?
Below is a simple example to reproduce the issue:
package Server;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = 5000;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server started. Waiting for connection...");
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connected.");

        // Hardcoded key and IV
        byte[] keyBytes = "1234567890123456".getBytes();
        byte[] ivBytes = "1234567890123456".getBytes();
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

        // Setup Cipher and Streams
        Cipher cipher_enc = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher_enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        Cipher cipher_dec = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher_dec.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        CipherOutputStream cipher_encOut = new CipherOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), cipher_enc);
        CipherInputStream cipher_decIn = new CipherInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream(), cipher_dec);

        System.out.println("Ciphers initialized.");
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(cipher_encOut);
        System.out.println("ObjectOutputStream initialized.");
        objOut.writeObject("Hello from Server!");
        objOut.flush();

        //REMOVING THIS BLOCK WILL MAKE THE CODE WORK JUST FINE
        ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(cipher_decIn);
        String message = (String) objIn.readObject();
        System.out.println("Message from server: " + message);

        objOut.close();
        objIn.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
        System.out.println("Server finished.");
    }
}

package Server;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 5000;
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
        System.out.println("Connected to server.");

        // Hardcoded key and IV
        byte[] keyBytes = "1234567890123456".getBytes();
        byte[] ivBytes = "1234567890123456".getBytes();
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

        // Setup Cipher and Streams
        Cipher cipher_enc = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher_enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        Cipher cipher_dec = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher_dec.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        CipherInputStream cipher_decIn = new CipherInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), cipher_dec);
        CipherOutputStream cipher_encOut = new CipherOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), cipher_enc);

        System.out.println("Ciphers initialized.");
        ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(cipher_decIn);
        System.out.println("ObjectInputStream initialized.");
        String message = (String) objIn.readObject();      
        System.out.println("Message from server: " + message);


        //REMOVING THIS BLOCK WILL MAKE THE CODE WORK JUST FINE
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(cipher_encOut);
        objOut.writeObject("Hello from Server!");
        objOut.flush();

        objIn.close();
        objOut.close();
        socket.close();
        System.out.println("Client disconnected.");
    }
}

In the example, the second ObjectInputStream should be initialized after the first message was sent, but somehow adding the marked code blocks actually breaks the code above it. I've tried initializing all streams before sending any type of data, but that also doesn't work. It might just be a fundamental misunderstanding about how these should behave, but I'm at the end of my rope. I'm almost certain that the problem has to do with the second ObjectOutputStreams header not arriving properly, maybe because of the CipherStreams Blocks or something, but I just can't figure it out.
Solution: Replace Block Cipher with Stream Cipher, Block Cipher causes Issues with the Header Transmission.
Ex.: use `AES/CTR/NoPadding
Edit: new ObjectInputStream() blocks does not at all have anything to do with the issue. The OutputStream does get initialized and should send the required header, the problem appears to me to be that the header doesn't get sent or arrive properly because of the underlying CipherInputStream/CipherOutputStream.

Create the object output stream before the object input stream.

I'd appreciate it if you'd read the Post before answering it, I'm aware that the OutputStream has to send a serialization header first. If that was the issue, the provided code sample would actually work.

I’d appreciate it if you would read the comment. Your code does not do what I have recommended here. If it did, it would work. Your object output stream is  constructed after the object input stream in the client.

Your comment is simply entirely misunderstanding what exactly is happening in that case. These two Classes run in separate threads, the ObjectOutputStream simply has to exist while the receiving ObjectInputStream is being initialized. It is completely irrelevant that the Clients ObjectInputStream is before Clients ObjectOutputStream. The client will block while waiting to receive the serial header from a ObjectOutputStream. The Server Provides the ObjectOutputStream for the client, then they should switch. What you recommended doesn't change the issue. I already tried.

@SmoothBren: I was the one who closed the question as duplicate. I was wrong, it is not a duplicate. The exact problem is a subtle interaction between the buffering the CipherInputStream/CipherOutputStream must do because AES is 16-byte block cipher and the way ObjectInputStream reads input to build objects. I have voted to reopen the question, and you have my apology.

I suspect you can make this work by using, for example, a stream cipher or AES CTR mode with NoPadding. In general, using cipher streams with object streams seems painful.

No need to apologize, the moderation is what makes stack so great. This was really helpful! It was definitely an Issue with the Blocks.
Have a nice day.
